# How configure SSL in Jboss Wildfly 8.1

Tags: ssl, jboss, keystore, wildfly

I have configured SSL in JBoss Wildfly 8.1. I have generated a keystore files and updated the standaolne.xml file as below

```
<security-realm name="security-realm">
  <server-identities> 
     <ssl> 
        <keystore path="security/keystore.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="changeit" key-password=" changeit"/> 
     </ssl>
  </server-identities> 
</security-realm>
```

The keystore-password and key-password is in cleartext. Simply we cannot show it in clear text. I want to encrypt the password. I tried a lot but could not credible help in this regard. So any body can help me in how to encrypt this password and how to use that in sandalone.xml file.

Answer (score 5):

You can masking passwords for WildFly using the **VaultTool**.

> **VaultTool** used in WildFly Application Server is used for
>   creating/using storage for secured attributes (e.g. passwords) which
>   can be later on used in WildFly configuration files in masked form.
>
> Thus users can use references to their secured attributes instead of
>   putting them in clear text form to configuration files.

First you need [create a Java Keystore to Store Sensitive Strings](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Security_Guide/Create_a_Java_Keystore_to_Store_Sensitive_Strings.html).

```
$ keytool -genseckey -alias vault -storetype jceks -keyalg AES -keysize 128 -storepass vault22 -keypass vault22 -validity 730 -keystore WILDFLY_HOME/vault/vault.keystore
```

Then initialize the Password Vault and store password for ssl keystore:

```
wildfly-8.1.0.Final/bin$ sh vault.sh

=========================================================================

  JBoss Vault Tool
  JBOSS_HOME: "wildfly-8.1.0.Final"
  JAVA: ""
  JAVA_OPTS: ""

=========================================================================

**********************************
****  JBoss Vault  ***************
**********************************
Please enter a Digit::   0: Start Interactive Session   1: Remove Interactive Session  2: Exit
0
Starting an interactive session
Enter directory to store encrypted files:/home/fsierra/vault/
Enter Keystore URL:home/fsierra/vault/vault.keystore
Enter Keystore password:
Enter Keystore password again:
Values match
Enter 8 character salt:12345678
Enter iteration count as a number (e.g.: 44):17
Enter Keystore Alias:Vault
Initializing Vault
ene 13, 2015 12:42:48 PM org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault init
INFO: PBOX000361: Default Security Vault Implementation Initialized and Ready
Vault Configuration in WildFly configuration file:
********************************************
...
</extensions>
<vault>
  <vault-option name="KEYSTORE_URL" value="/home/fsierra/vault/vault.keystore"/>
  <vault-option name="KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" value="MASK-49SI2WfwF1X"/>
  <vault-option name="KEYSTORE_ALIAS" value="Vault"/>
  <vault-option name="SALT" value="12345678"/>
  <vault-option name="ITERATION_COUNT" value="17"/>
  <vault-option name="ENC_FILE_DIR" value="/home/fsierra/vault/"/>
</vault><management> ...
********************************************
Vault is initialized and ready for use
Handshake with Vault complete
Please enter a Digit::   0: Store a secured attribute  1: Check whether a secured attribute exists  2: Exit
0
Task: Store a secured attribute
Please enter secured attribute value (such as password):
Please enter secured attribute value (such as password) again:
Values match
Enter Vault Block:keystore
Enter Attribute Name:password
Secured attribute value has been stored in Vault.
Please make note of the following:
********************************************
Vault Block:keystore
Attribute Name:password
Configuration should be done as follows:
VAULT::keystore::password::1
********************************************
Please enter a Digit::   0: Store a secured attribute  1: Check whether a secured attribute exists  2: Exit
```

Finally  keystore password has been masked for use in configuration files and deployments.

Eg (standalone.xml):

```xml
<extensions>  
    ...  
</extensions>  
<vault>  
    <vault-option name="KEYSTORE_URL" value="/home/fsierra/vault/vault.keystore"/>
    <vault-option name="KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" value="MASK-49SI2WfwF1X"/>
    <vault-option name="KEYSTORE_ALIAS" value="Vault"/>
    <vault-option name="SALT" value="12345678"/>
    <vault-option name="ITERATION_COUNT" value="17"/>
    <vault-option name="ENC_FILE_DIR" value="/home/fsierra/vault/"/>
</vault>
<management>
    <security-realms>
        ...

        <security-realm name="SslRealm">
            <server-identities>
                    <ssl>
                        <keystore path="ssl.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="${VAULT::keystore::password::1}"/>
                    </ssl>
            </server-identities>
        </security-realm>
    </security-realms>
</management>
```

References:

- [Masking passwords for WildFly using non-interactive VaultTool](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/MaskingPasswordsForWildFlyUsingNon-interactiveVaultTool)
- [Mask the Keystore Password and Initialize the Password Vault](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Security_Guide/Mask_the_Keystore_Password_and_Initialize_the_Password_Vault..html)
- [JBoss AS7 Securing Passwords](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7SecuringPasswords)
- [AS7: Utilising masked passwords via the vault](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/AS7UtilisingMaskedPasswordsViaTheVault)